# matplotlib streamplot error for a specific number of gridpoints

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

The following minimal code snippet fails when `n=29` but works when `n=28` or `n=30`.

```python
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0,1,n)
plt.streamplot(x,x,np.meshgrid(x,x)[0],np.meshgrid(x,x)[1])
plt.show()
```

The error given when `n=29` is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/streamplot.py in _integrate_rk12(x0, y0, dmap, f, maxlength)
    526         try:
--> 527             k1x, k1y = f(xi, yi)
    528             k2x, k2y = f(xi + ds * k1x,

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/streamplot.py in backward_time(xi, yi)
    434     def backward_time(xi, yi):
--> 435         dxi, dyi = forward_time(xi, yi)
    436         return -dxi, -dyi

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/streamplot.py in forward_time(xi, yi)
    425     def forward_time(xi, yi):
--> 426         ds_dt = interpgrid(speed, xi, yi)
    427         if ds_dt == 0:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/streamplot.py in interpgrid(a, xi, yi)
    619     a00 = a[y, x]
--> 620     a01 = a[y, xn]
    621     a10 = a[yn, x]

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py in __getitem__(self, indx)
   3196         # So it's easier to stick to the current version
-> 3197         dout = self.data[indx]
   3198         _mask = self._mask

IndexError: index 29 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 29
```

This has been driving me crazy for a while. The plots are generated when n=28 or n=30. I even checked the code on google collab to make sure that I did not screw up my libraries somehow.

[Here's the link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Z5oylZaRww9xeUrlRWOnQWbwSlTRIE6c)

Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: xref: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12133

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of an indexing error in the matplotlib 2.2.x series. Solved in matplotlib 3.x with [this patch](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/11455). The github issue for the bug I created is [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12133). The patch might get backported to 2.2.x